# Java Mail timeout & connectiontimeout handling

Tags: java, exception, email, jakarta-mail

I'm using JavaMail to send email requests to an SMTP server.

I would like to set both **"mail.smtp.connectiontimeout"** and **"mail.smtp.timeout"** properties within my code.

Programmatically, I want to catch both when *timeout* and/or *connectiontimeout* operations are reached in Java and handle things accordingly. Handling in the sense, I need to retry the same email once again the next time.

How do I handle this in Java/JavaMail?  Is it possible to catch & handle this timeout operations?

**EDIT**

Also, is it possible to simulate/reproduce this timeout operation on my own assuming I've complete administration access to the SMTP server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering your second question: On your test machine just DROP all outgoing connections to your SMTP Server with iptables:

```
   iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.20 --dport 25 -j DROP
```

This way it does look like an unresponsive smtp server and you can test your exception handling.

Comment: Thanks for that simulation steps. I'll try that.

Answer (score 3):

All:

Am answering my question, after experiencing this on my own.

> How do I handle this in Java/JavaMail?
>   Is it possible to catch & handle this
>   timeout operations?

Yes, it is automatically thrown as **javax.mail.MessagingException**.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1462)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1260)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
```

This exception is thrown exactly at this line:

> Transport.connect();

Only open question I've now is "**Is it possible to simulate/reproduce this timeout operation on my own assuming I've complete administration access to the SMTP server?**"

Any ideas from experts?