# How to handle concurrency in Java or Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have a piece of code to send the mail, Before sending the mail i have to override the default smtp settings with the current logged in user email and after i have to revert it, So there is a concurrency issue When two or more users trying to send the mails, So how to get rid of this.

Comment: Any sort of code to go along with this, so we can see what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: why overriding and then reverting? Why is that necessary? Try gpars for groovy. Should have what you need.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking (as you did not provide code): if multiple threads are using a single resource in a configure-then-use manner then you should put the data into an object (`new MailSendRequest(smtpconfig, message)`´and put these into a queue. A different `Thread` should be watching this queue and process the `MailSendRequests` one-by-one bypassing the concurrency problem. (In this specific case sending out the mails should be delayed anyway because sending a bulk of them at once is not considered a good practice by ISP-s. They usually send out smaller batches of mails periodically.)

Answer (score 2):

jabal's solution is exactly what I'd suggest as well. Specifically, I'd suggest you use the [SingleThreadExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) service. It does exactly what jabal suggests: you can queue your mail requests, and one thread will process them in order.

I notice though that you are working with a task that has potential high latency issues (one great reason to stick this on a queue somewhere else!). I'd suggest you make sure to explicitly [set a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773108/java-mail-timeout-connectiontimeout-handling) so that you know the max time a task should take, and that you [use the submit method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29) of your executor so that you can handle any potential errors you encounter along the way.

Answer (score 1):

First way:
You need locking. Here is what I would do:

```
void sendMail(){
    syncronize(smtp){
       //alter smtp mail object
       smtp.sentMail();
       //revert smtp mail object
    }
}
```

when code execution enters to `syncronize` block it locks the smtp object, then whoever comes to locked object, they waits till it gets resolved.

Second way:
Or using shared `Lock` object.

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
void sendMail(){
       lock.lock();
       //alter smtp mail object
       smtp.sentMail();
       //revert smtp mail object
      lock.unLock(); 
    }
```

}

It is kind a transaction

Comment: which one of this solution do you prefer

Comment: `ReentrantLock` is more powerful, but here I would use 1st one. I believe `syncronized(smtp)`  is exactly for this kind of purpose.